# Remove duplicates based on Timestamp Kusto Query

Tags: database, relational-database, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have two tables like the ones below in Kusto. I am trying to join the tables based on the name/usernames but keep the rows from the second table even if there is no match for the first table, and also remove duplicates from the second table based on timestamp if the username and email are the same (in which case I would keep the info from the most recent -- latest timestamp)

```
Table 1

Name | pets | color | city
A    | A1   | blue  | NYC
A    | A2   | blue  | NYC
A    | A3   | blue  | NYC
B    | B1   | red   | Boston
C    | C1   | yellow| Miami
C    | C2   | yellow| Miami

Table 2

username | email          | school   | timestamp
A        | a@whatever.com | schoolA  | 10pm
B        | b@whatever.com | schoolB1 | 10pm
B        | b@whatever.com | schoolB2 | 11pm
C        | c@whatever.com | schoolC  | 9pm
D        | d@whatever.com | schoolD  | 11pm
E        | e@whatever.com | schoolE  | 10pm

Table results I want

name | pets | color  | city  | email          | school   | timestamp
A    | A1   | blue   | NYC   | a@whatever.com | schoolA  | 10pm
A    | A2   | blue   | NYC   | a@whatever.com | schoolA  | 10pm
A    | A3   | blue   | NYC   | a@whatever.com | schoolA  | 10pm
B    | B1   | red    | Boston| b@whatever.com | schoolB2 | 11pm
C    | C1   | yellow | Miami | c@whatever.com | schoolC  | 9pm
C    | C2   | yellow | Miami | c@whatever.com | schoolC  | 9pm
D    |      |        |       | d@whatever.com | schoolD  | 11pm
E    |      |        |       | e@whatever.com | schoolE  | 10pm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the following query could work.

It uses:

- [arg_max() (aggregation function)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction): *"remove duplicates from the second table based on timestamp if the username and email are the same (in which case I would keep the info from the most recent -- latest timestamp)*"
- [Right outer-join flavor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#right-outer-join-flavor): *"keep the rows from the second table even if there is no match for the first table"*

```
let T1 = datatable(name:string, pets:string, color:string, city:string)
[
    "A", "A1", "blue",   "NYC",
    "A", "A2", "blue",   "NYC",
    "A", "A3", "blue",   "NYC",
    "B", "B1", "red ",   "Boston",
    "C", "C1", "yellow", "Miami",
    "C", "C2", "yellow", "Miami",
]
;
let T2 = datatable(username:string, email:string, school:string, timestamp:datetime)
[
    "A", "a@whatever.com", "schoolA",  datetime(2020-11-24 22:00),
    "B", "b@whatever.com", "schoolB1", datetime(2020-11-24 22:00),
    "B", "b@whatever.com", "schoolB2", datetime(2020-11-24 23:00),
    "C", "c@whatever.com", "schoolC",  datetime(2020-11-24 21:00),
    "D", "d@whatever.com", "schoolD",  datetime(2020-11-24 23:00),
    "E", "e@whatever.com", "schoolE",  datetime(2020-11-24 22:00),
]
;
T1
| join kind=rightouter (
    T2
    | summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by username, email
) on $left.name == $right.username
| project name = username, pets, color, city, email, school, timestamp
| order by name asc, pets asc
```

```
| name | pets | color  | city   | email          | school   | timestamp                   |
|------|------|--------|--------|----------------|----------|-----------------------------|
| A    | A1   | blue   | NYC    | a@whatever.com | schoolA  | 2020-11-24 22:00:00.0000000 |
| A    | A2   | blue   | NYC    | a@whatever.com | schoolA  | 2020-11-24 22:00:00.0000000 |
| A    | A3   | blue   | NYC    | a@whatever.com | schoolA  | 2020-11-24 22:00:00.0000000 |
| B    | B1   | red    | Boston | b@whatever.com | schoolB2 | 2020-11-24 23:00:00.0000000 |
| C    | C1   | yellow | Miami  | c@whatever.com | schoolC  | 2020-11-24 21:00:00.0000000 |
| C    | C2   | yellow | Miami  | c@whatever.com | schoolC  | 2020-11-24 21:00:00.0000000 |
| D    |      |        |        | d@whatever.com | schoolD  | 2020-11-24 23:00:00.0000000 |
| E    |      |        |        | e@whatever.com | schoolE  | 2020-11-24 22:00:00.0000000 |
```